# Flutter assets: pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a simple asset to my flutter project.

Here's my pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    assets:
      - assets/profile.orwell

  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  uuid:
    path: ./lib/liborwellprofile/dart-uuid
  orwell_flutter_plugin:
    path: ./orwell_flutter_plugin
```

I get the error:

```
Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.

   ╷

21 │ ┌     sdk: flutter

22 │ │     assets:

23 │ │       - assets/profile.orwell

24 │ │ 

25 │ │   json_annotation: ^3.0.1
   │ └──^
```

When I take out the `assets:...`, everything works fine.

I just did as https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images instructs. What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding the `assets` under `dependencies` which shouldn't be.

Try this:

```dart
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  uuid:
    path: ./lib/liborwellprofile/dart-uuid
  orwell_flutter_plugin:
    path: ./orwell_flutter_plugin

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/profile.orwell
```